# Linking to Google PlusOne, without embedding the button (for privacy reasons)

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, privacy, google-plus-one

It seems that Google only offers code to *embed* the +1 button.

However, there are heavy *privacy concerns* (plus quite some load time) associated with it.

For some pointers about the privacy and legal issues associated with Facebook like and Google +1, see: [Like button and privacy concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187673/like-button-and-privacy-concern)

A common workaround seems to be a **[two-click solution](http://www.heise.de/extras/socialshareprivacy/)**<sup>German</sup> ([also discussed on slashdot](http://yro.slashdot.org/story/11/09/03/0115241/Heises-Two-Clicks-For-More-Privacy-vs-Facebook)<sup>English</sup>), where the first click *enables* the button (loading the javascript from Google), the second then is on the regular +1 button.

However, I do not want to implement this two-click solution either. Largely because **the Google +1 button is ugly as hell, and doesn't fit to the page layout**.

What I'm really looking for is a separate web page, where the user can essentially *confirm* that he likes the page. This page can live on google.com, and essentially this would be the second click. I'm not trying to trick people into +1'ing the page. The second click is all fine with me. I just don't want to *force* them to load the plusone button (and I don't like its looks).

There seems to be the option of

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=<URL>
```

which however is a *share on Google+*, not a *+1*.

I've seen this URL, too:

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=<URL>
```

(see e.g. here: [Adding a Google Plus (one or share) link to an email newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157411/adding-a-google-plus-one-or-share-link-to-an-email-newsletter)) but I cannot submit this form (i.e. doesn't seem to work).

The best *working* solutions seems to be the two-click approach. :-(

**Update**: the url, `https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=<URL>` actually does seem to work. It was just my privacy proxy breaking it. Then it seems to be more of a "Google+ share" dialog. I'm not yet happy with this result (in particular, since this doesn't seem to be an advocated approach for Google, and they can at any point consider to ban the site, I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that I'm now looking into is fairly trivial:

I've set up a **Google Plus page** for the web site, and the "plus" button sends user there. In fact just like the Facebook icon I'm using. Then the users get the *full choice of interaction options*, including +1, but also circling and sharing.

First of all, this obviously should not violate any g+ policies. Secondly, it is a fairly transparent behaviour for the users. The "plus" button takes them to Google plus, where they see the usual plus UI.

Secondly, it's still just two clicks to "+1". So it is not worse than any other data privacy compliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only officially supported method of +1'ing a URL is with the +1 button. Either always loading or loading it on a second click.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](http://atlchris.com/1665/how-to-create-custom-share-buttons-for-all-the-popular-social-services/).

The problem is, social sites accepts your own "share" forms, but only if the link is URL encoded.

In Wordpress, a custom Google+ button that I'm using without the official API, and it's currently working, is this following code:

```
<a href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php print(urlencode(get_permalink())); ?>+<?php print(urlencode(the_title())); ?>" title="Share this story on google+">google+</a>
```

Hope it helps, go to the link above for a list of the rest of the social sites links. :)