# PHP : Is it Possible to do Google +1 via API?

Tags: php, google-plus, google-plus-one

Is there any Google api available ?

Comment: I googled but, its not possible via api..Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Evidently you didn't google hard enough, or used the wrong search terms. look at @Mazaka s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question more succinctly:

- There is no +1 API call for the PHP client library that will +1 a URL, most likely due to the potential for abuse
- You can only trigger +1 actions [using the +1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) which must be rendered using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

[May be this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) just typed into google "google php api".

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248204/linking-to-google-plusone-without-embedding-the-button-for-privacy-reasons)